# How do I load sorl's thumbnail template tag in all my templates

Tags: django, django-templates, sorl-thumbnail

Given that sorl isn't an app directory wide and the template tag definition lives in the virtualenv dir

I want to be able to use {% thumbnail .... %} without having to use {% load thumbnail %} first. It can't be loaded in the layout apparently.

I know it is know critical but it would be nice %}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy paste the following code to an **init**.py that gets loaded,

```
from django import template
template.add_to_builtins('sorl.thumbnail.templatetags.thumbnail')
```

Comment: Would you recoomendI import it to settings? Or just in teh app/<name>/__init__.py

Comment: app/<name>/__init__.py should be fine

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible.

["When you load a custom tag or filter library, the tags/filters are only made available to the current template -- not any parent or child templates along the template-inheritance path."](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#custom-libraries-and-template-inheritance)

So you'll have to declare `{% load thumbnail %}` in every template that uses the `thumbnail` tag.

Comment: Yep. That's the way custom template tags work. No way around it.